# Is my routine and exercise ok for good biceps and 4 or 6 pack abs

Tags: exercise, abdominals, biceps

I will be 21 years old in january 2014. Height=5.8 foot approx  weight= 65kg / 143.3 pound approx.

```
I do 100 push ups in 4 sets = 25+25+25+25 and 80 leg raises in 4 sets = 20+20+20+20 
(I complete it in 40 to 45 mins). 
I do it 5 days a week, Monday to Friday and take rest on Saturday and Sunday
to relax muscles.
```

Is it ok to build good biceps and 4 or 6 pack abs? I am a computer science student so I have to spend much time sitting in front of computer and don't get much time to walk or play any sports.

```
I think I walk nearly half a mile or little more than this in my daily routine.
I sleep 6 hours or 6 and a half hour every night.
```

Comment: As Dave points out in his answer, none of the exercises you do target your biceps in any appreciable way. I'd suggest doing some [research or muscles are their movements](http://www.exrx.net/Lists/Directory.html) before asking your next qeustion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing any bicep exercises, so **no**, this doesn't look like a good plan to get pretty biceps. Add some pulling exercises like pull-ups, chin-ups, or curls.

For abs, you'll need to do a little ab work (such as your leg raises), but more importantly you'll need [low body fat through diet and cardio](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/13504/1771).

It's not part of your question, but since you're a programmer, I'd definitely recommend [working on posture](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/7223/1771), pulling exercises, and squats to avoid a "computer hunch" and tight hips.

Comment: you mean push up are not for biceps ??

Comment: @user2851468 Correct. Push-ups are great, especially for your chest, triceps, and shoulders, but they don't work the biceps much.