# This Exercise Enough for me in a day?

Tags: exercise, training, back-pain, neck

As a software developer. We have to sit in a chair for whole day. And we don't get a time for anything else. Get a back Pain, and neck pain. I am posting Images here so that it helps a bit the people. And can anyone tell me. What else exercises need to be done? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: -1 What is the question here? How does it related to the image? And why has the copyright notice been [removed from the image](http://p.blog.csdn.net/images/p_blog_csdn_net/axingabc/k200712610332.jpg)?

Comment: " And we don't get a time for anything else." Make Time.  If you're even marginally capable, you can write your own check in today's job market as a programmer.  Your current employer is not worth decades of poor health.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what the question is when it's nothing but images. Images should supplement your question, not replace them (and for some of us, imgur is blocked on firewalls).

Comment: Also see this other question about [exercises programmers can do](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/6/241).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My qualification for answering this**

I am no fitness expert beside being involved in sports even before teen years. In my teens and early adult life i would train 4 to 6 days a week, until I started working. I am also a software developer, and been in industry for way more than an hand full so I can relate easily to you.

**Short answer**

Yes. Anything is way better than nothing, although walking more, even around the office, while you stretch may be a better option. They may not make you lose weight but will improve you life quality, and may be enough for removing those pains you say your have.

**Long answer**

**First** of all, lets step out of fitness, since neck and back pain may not be related to it. Sometimes you need to have a better chair or posture at work. We do sit a lot, even more than we are suppose to. There are even **few** offices that offer [standing desk](http://mashable.com/2011/04/22/standup-desks/) for their workers, I've already tried to implement that in my actual office. I can say it's a good experience, but I am sitting right now as everyone else.

**Second**, you say

> we don't get a time for anything else

Although I know the felling, and almost everyone around me says that, believe me, most of times is untrue, and I would bet on 99,99% of the times. I know how a start up can be time consuming, or how a large corporation can be demanding, I had to travel or work at night due to time differences to customer, etc. Simply put, Software developing is demanding, and you pass most of the time sitting in a chair. When I started working my first full time developer job I went from super active to couch potato in a few weeks. I tried to exercise on week-end, but when I wasn't working I was trying to catch with my social or family life.

**The solution**

Don't have time, and wish to exercise more, make time then. Get up early in the morning, or get into bed late. To begin, start with 5-10 minutes of strength workout just before you take you bath in the morning or before bed time, you can find a lot of [web training pages](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&q=10%20minute%20fitness%20programs) and I bet that an equal volume of apps for you favourite smart phone. After a few weeks, in your routine, it's up to you, maintain it, increase the workout time, or the intensity of it.

I started with low time consuming training programs like [this](http://hundredpushups.com/) since you don't need anything more than your own weigh and can be done in our bedroom.
If you have a tight schedule avoid gyms and big groups sports.
Choose a small and loose but steady training program. You can do it.

**Most of all be persistent**, at first it's hard, if it was easy everybody would do it. But after a time it will be like any other routine.

Answer (score 1):

Deadlifts, squats, benchpress, military press and Chins? :)

No but seriously, I really believe a good strength program is something everybody should be doing. Especially people with sedentary office jobs. Don't lift to look good, lift for a well functioning movement apparatus.

Also, try to walk as much you can. Go to a bathroom further away. Go talk to people instead of mailing. Use the stairs instead of elevator etc. etc. If you have a height adjustable table you might also consider working standing up.