# How can I fix my 'computer body'?

Tags: posture, physique

I have spent so many years at the computer.  I work out and run so I am toned.  Weights once a week (deadlift, squats, just started shrugs).  I run 1-3 times a week, 3 miles.  Three times a week I do either planks or pull-ups (hand forward), three times a week I do glute bridges (for anterior pelvic tilt) and push ups.  On the days I work out I do conditioning: various stretches, psoas with a tennis ball, cobra, stretching hip flexors, etc.

Despite all this, I still have a 'geek body'.  My anterior pelvic tilt, resulting in its pushing my butt and stomach out, as well as snapping in my hip flexors when I do sit ups for flutter kicks, isn't going away.  My shoulders seem to go forward too much, and if I roll my shoulders back to loosen them up, they click a lot.  My scapula go out a bit too much, with the right one going out much further, though that's probably due to a very mild scoliosis on that side.  My elbows click.  The backs of my hands face forward.  My bicep femoris muscles in the legs are very tight, and begin to hurt if I walk all day; I try to massage them with 'the stick' a couple of times a week.

What can I do?  The above exercises haven't done much for me.  Even in the old days, when people were so active and healthy, they didn't move 16 hours a day.  Why isn't my frequent breaks througout the day, workout schedule 3 times a week, and getting out and about a couple of times a day fixing this?

**Edit**

When I squat I go to around parallel.  My heels stay on the ground.  I squat between 180 and 200 lbs.  I squat normally once a week.

Comment: Check out this [pdf with stretches](http://kaasplateau.com/stretches.pdf) -- it's been making the rounds around Reddit since forever and is a nice routine fixing the most common problems. If you are serious about your fitness, consider taking up a beginner barbell (eg. Starting Strength or Stronglifts) or bodyweight (eg. [fitloop](http://www.fitloop.co/)) routine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exercises for a programmer sitting by the PC all day](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6/exercises-for-a-programmer-sitting-by-the-pc-all-day)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm not sure a beginner program would help -- I'm no expert but I do dl and squat around 200, do 100 - 150 push ups 3x a week.  I did stronglifts for awhile and it was great.  But nothing seems to fix my arms, shoulders, and hip.

Comment: Oh, and thank you for that link.  I'll definitely check it out.

Comment: @JayDee When you squat, do you go past parallel?  Are your heels on the ground?  I ask because I feel full-range squats would go a long way in solving your problems.

Comment: Everything up to 1.5x bodyweight squat is still considered a novice in barbell lifts. Also consider the bodyweight routine, gymnastics is **not** easy. 100-150 pushups are just an endurance thing, there is not strength component (not to mention, they tend to exacerbate some of the issues you mentioned, eg the hunched shoulders)

Comment: In addition to the daily stretching, you may want to consider some professional body work by a massage therapist or physical therapist who works from an  "Anatomy Trains" standpoint.  They recognize the connections from your toe to your head by continuous layers of connective tissue (muscle, bones, fascia.)  They can also show you how to use a foam roller to address your restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically to the hip flexors problem. I have the exact same problem, and I have significantly improved it with some intense hip flexor stretching. The kinds of stretches that you find on the Internet don't help all that much, so I designed my own.

I basically just work on doing a front split, while supporting my upper body on both sides with a couple of chairs.  I just slowly sink into the split while keeping my abs flexed and while leaning back at the pelvis (not the waist).

I also saw a trigger point massage therapist for a while which resulted in definite temporary improvement, but I didn't notice anything permanent.

I'm considering an assisted stretching therapist, but <strike>have not tried it yet</strike> my old trigger point therapist did do some assisted stretching on me, and it was pretty amazing how much easier it was with the second person and some leverage. Admittedly, we only tried this a few times.

Answer (score 1):

You've been at a desk for many years, it may simply take a long time for your efforts to show progress.

Beyond what you've tried, I would strongly recommend a standing desk. Part of your problem may be that you do all this work just to return to the same position (sitting at a desk) making it difficult for your body to change.  That's conjecture obviously, but a standing desk has worked wonders for me.

Standing or sitting, a professional ergonomic assessment would also be valuable.

Put simply, if being at a desk all day is causing problems the best remedy will be fixing your desk, not trying to mitigate it's problems with exercise.

Comment: +1 for standing desk. I have an electrical elevate/lower desk, and spent a lot of time standing because I can literally *feel* my back rejoicing. My job also spent quite a bit of money buying these for our workplace. It's a godsend.

Comment: As a caveat, prolonged standing isn't great for you either. There do exist desks that allow easy transitioning between the two. Or just get up and walk for a minute or two every hour, which has been found to basically erase any damage done by prolonged sitting.