# what is the best routine for someone that work and studying a lot

Tags: workout-routines, workout, body-fat

Hello everyone I am new here so I am developer(I make software for my client). Yesterday, my doctor said me that I need do work out everyday and eat well.

I am not expert in this area and I need help/

I get up 6 AM and then I go to school from 7 AM to 1 PM, ten I go to work from 1 PM to 9 PM.

My question:

What is the best routine for my body and feel well with my body? My doctor said that I need to work out because I am a little little fat. If I do not  work out it is bad for my body in the future.

Do you have any tips for me?

Sorry if my question is not good, but I do not know about this area(fitness) and this site is the only one I found at stackexchange about work out. If another exists, please tell me in a comments.

If my question is not complete, please tell me what I  need for a complete question.

Comment: Asking for a "best routine" is kind of vague, what I would suggest is to sit down and figure out some specific goals, and then refine your question a bit more. Also I would recommend looking around, there are quite a few similar questions, such as https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6/exercises-for-a-programmer-sitting-by-the-pc-all-day

Comment: oh thankyou :) sorry if my  question is bad I will try to edit my  question in some best

Comment: Did your doctor diagnose you with any issues? Prediabetes, diabetes, high cholesterol, hypertension, metabolic syndrome, or anything of the like?  Based on diagnoses, this can change a suggested program.  Also, what are you goals to achieve for a workout?  If your doctor presented you with no restrictions, then a suggested program could be many, many things depending on what you would like to do.  Do you want to look like a body builder, run a marathon, compete in CrossFit, enter into a physique competition, get generally fit, or really strong like a power lifter?

Comment: You already have a pretty full schedule. How much time to you plan for working out? Where? Do you have access to something, perhaps at the company you work for, do you have space and so on? What do you want to do? What do you like to do? Do you have any goals yourself?

Comment: @SeanPerkins  "Did your doctor diagnose you with any issues?" yep the doctor said me that I am a little fat  ,and that I can not breathe that's why I need to do work out I did not understand a lot the doctor

Comment: What do you have access to for a gym?  Do you have any injuries that would not allow you to perform any exercises or low- or high-intensity cardio?  Also, to lose weight (body fat), you need to change your diet, getting thin and lean starts in the kitchen, then on to a well-programmed exercise regimen.

Comment: no injuries ohh :( I am confuce I did not understand could help me with a guide :( ok first should I do a diet? but first should ask to my doctor? rigth?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, good quality sleep and hydration. Coupled with healthy foods, and reasonable amounts of caffeine.

That said, since you’re very busy, I would recommend trying to stand while working, as opposed to sitting at a desk, to keep your body moving and your rest state burning calories.

If possible, do a set of 10 pushups, 10 air squats, and 10 sit-ups at the top of every hour - should only take a couple minutes and will get you moving towards basic fitness.

Comment: what time should I sleep? I sleep 4 or 5 hours

Comment: Sleep varies slightly based on the person. I would test yourself and see what feels best. But if I had to choose, I would say 7-8 hours. And if you’re sitting at a desk all day, spend at least 20 minutes a day stretching and straightening your body.